# Is there any API function for shutting down Windows while installing any pending updates?

Tags: windows, winapi, shutdown, system-shutdown

I know the `ExitWindowsEx()` API function which simply shuts down Windows. But as far as I know, you cannot make Windows install any pending updates with it.

Is there any API support for installing any pending updates (in that standard blue screen which says "*n of m updates have installed - Please don't turn off or unplug your PC, Windows will shut down itself*") then shutting down Windows (equivalent to clicking the "Install updates and shutdown" menu option of the Windows user interface)?

(OS Version: Windows XP and higher.)

Comment: InitiateShutdown(SHUTDOWN_INSTALL_UPDATES)?

Comment: @RaymondChen he said it has to work on XP. InitiateShutdown requires Vista/WS2K8

Comment: XP didn't have the concept of installing updates on shutdown afaik.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The best you can do is call `InitiateShutdown` and include the `SHUTDOWN_INSTALL_UPDATES` flag on Vista and higher. Windows XP does not support programmatically shutting down with updates.